# How to get name of a specific item in array and increment its value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a simple cart, for a homework project. I would like to ask, what would be the best way to take an item from array and increment its value by one? I have 25 items in the array, and each of them has unique name, so I am not using any IDs. Would it be possible to take these items by their name value?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a2faab1b70.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="database.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <title>Nákupný košík</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    
<script type="text/babel">

let sklad = localStorage.getItem('basket');
basket.push(JSON.parse(sklad));

class Basket extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        counter: basket.length,
        basket: basket
      };

      this.clearCart = () => {
    basket = [];
    localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basket));
    this.setState(basket);
    }}
    
    addItem = (a) => { //Here is the problem, how can I increment value of a specific item?
    this.setState({[a.target.name]: this.state.counter + 1});
    
  }

  removeItem = (a) => { //Here is the problem, how can I decrement value of a specific item?
    this.setState({[a.target.name]: this.state.counter - 1})
  }

   

    render() {
        return  <div>
        {basket[0]?.map((items) =>
      <div>
        <div>{items.name}, {this.state.counter}x, Cena {items.price} <button onClick={this.addItem}>+</button> <button onClick={this.removeItem}>-</button></div>
      </div>
      )} 
      
      <div id="counter">Počet položiek v košíku {basket[0]?.length + this.state.counter -1}</div> 
      <button onClick={this.clearCart} >Vyprázdniť košík</button>
      
      </div> 
      
    } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Basket/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

</script>

</body>
</html>



//Database with items

let basket = [];

let products = [
{
   type: "mb",
   name: "Asus Motherboard",
   price: "320",
   link: "products/asusmb.html",
   image: "/Eshop_project/img/asusmb.jfif",
},

{
   type: "cpu",
   name: "Intel Core i3",
   price: "150",
   image: "../img/corei3.jfif",
},

{
   type: "cpu",
   name: "Intel Core i5",
   price: "300",
   image: "../img/corei5.jfif",
},

{
   type: "cpu",
   name: "Intel Core i7",
   price: "450",
   image: "../img/corei7.jfif",
},

{
   type: "cpu",
   name: "Intel Core i9",
   price: "600",
   image: "../img/corei9.jfif",
},

{
   type: "ram",
   name: "Corsair 16gb",
   price: "80",
   image: "../img/corsair16gb.jfif",
},

{
   type: "psu",
   name: "Corsair PSU",
   price: "100",
   image: "../img/corsairpsu.jfif",
},

{
   type: "ram",
   name: "Crucial 32gb",
   price: "160",
   image: "../img/crucial32gb.jfif",
},

{
   type: "gpu",
   name: "Nvidia Geforce RTX3070",
   price: "750",
   image: "../img/gforce 3070.jfif",
},

{
   type: "gpu",
   name: "Nvidia Geforce RTX 3080",
   price: "950",
   image: "../img/gforce_3080.jfif",
},

{
   type: "gpu",
   name: "Nvidia Geforce RTX 3090",
   price: "1200",
   image: "../img/gforce_3090.jfif",
},

{
   type: "mb",
   name: "Gigabyte Motherboard",
   price: "400",
   image: "../img/gigabytemb.jfif",
},

{
   type: "psu",
   name: "Gigabyte PSU",
   price: "80",
   image: "../img/gigabytepsu.jfif",
},

{
   type: "ram",
   name: "Kingston 16gb",
   price: "90",
   image: "../img/kingston16gb.jfif",
},

{
   type: "mb",
   name: "MSI Motherboard",
   price: "300",
   image: "../img/msimb.jfif",
},

{
   type: "case",
   name: "Phanteks Case",
   price: "70",
   image: "../img/Phaktekscase.jfif",
},

{
   type: "gpu",
   name: "AMD Radeon 6500",
   price: "500",
   image: "../img/radeon_6500.jfif",
},

{
   type: "gpu",
   name: "AMD Radeon 6800",
   price: "650",
   image: "../img/radeon_6800.jfif",
},

{
   type: "gpu",
   name: "AMD Radeon 6900",
   price: "800",
   image: "../img/radeon_6900.jfif",
},

{
   type: "cpu",
   name: "AMD Ryzen 3790",
   price: "400",
   image: "../img/ryzen3790.jfif",
},

{
   type: "cpu",
   name: "AMD Ryzen 5600",
   price: "550",
   image: "../img/ryzen5600.jfif",
},

{
   type: "cpu",
   name: "AMD Ryzen 5800",
   price: "700",
   image: "../img/ryzen5800.jfif",
},

{
   type: "psu",
   name: "Seasonic PSU",
   price: "95",
   image: "../img/seasonicpsu.jfif",
},

{
   type: "case",
   name: "Zalmancase",
   price: "90",
   image: "../img/zalmancase.jfif",
},

{
   type: "psu",
   name: "Evga PSU",
   price: "80",
   image: "../img/evgapsu.jfif",
}

]
localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your coding style, and how its going to self-document.

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters):

```js
const products=[{type:"mb",name:"Asus Motherboard",price:"320",link:"products/asusmb.html",image:"/Eshop_project/img/asusmb.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"Intel Core i3",price:"150",image:"../img/corei3.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"Intel Core i5",price:"300",image:"../img/corei5.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"Intel Core i7",price:"450",image:"../img/corei7.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"Intel Core i9",price:"600",image:"../img/corei9.jfif"},{type:"ram",name:"Corsair 16gb",price:"80",image:"../img/corsair16gb.jfif"},{type:"psu",name:"Corsair PSU",price:"100",image:"../img/corsairpsu.jfif"},{type:"ram",name:"Crucial 32gb",price:"160",image:"../img/crucial32gb.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"Nvidia Geforce RTX3070",price:"750",image:"../img/gforce 3070.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"Nvidia Geforce RTX 3080",price:"950",image:"../img/gforce_3080.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"Nvidia Geforce RTX 3090",price:"1200",image:"../img/gforce_3090.jfif"},{type:"mb",name:"Gigabyte Motherboard",price:"400",image:"../img/gigabytemb.jfif"},{type:"psu",name:"Gigabyte PSU",price:"80",image:"../img/gigabytepsu.jfif"},{type:"ram",name:"Kingston 16gb",price:"90",image:"../img/kingston16gb.jfif"},{type:"mb",name:"MSI Motherboard",price:"300",image:"../img/msimb.jfif"},{type:"case",name:"Phanteks Case",price:"70",image:"../img/Phaktekscase.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"AMD Radeon 6500",price:"500",image:"../img/radeon_6500.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"AMD Radeon 6800",price:"650",image:"../img/radeon_6800.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"AMD Radeon 6900",price:"800",image:"../img/radeon_6900.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"AMD Ryzen 3790",price:"400",image:"../img/ryzen3790.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"AMD Ryzen 5600",price:"550",image:"../img/ryzen5600.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"AMD Ryzen 5800",price:"700",image:"../img/ryzen5800.jfif"},{type:"psu",name:"Seasonic PSU",price:"95",image:"../img/seasonicpsu.jfif"},{type:"case",name:"Zalmancase",price:"90",image:"../img/zalmancase.jfif"},{type:"psu",name:"Evga PSU",price:"80",image:"../img/evgapsu.jfif"}];

const search = 'Corsair 16gb';

// Iterate over the objects and return each in its initial
// state except the one that you increase the price for
const newProducts = products.map(product => {
  if (product.name === search) ++product.price;
  return product;
});

console.log(newProducts);
```

Or maybe [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the object, increase the price, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array to remove that object, and then create an updated array from the filtered array, and the new updated object.

```js
const products=[{type:"mb",name:"Asus Motherboard",price:"320",link:"products/asusmb.html",image:"/Eshop_project/img/asusmb.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"Intel Core i3",price:"150",image:"../img/corei3.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"Intel Core i5",price:"300",image:"../img/corei5.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"Intel Core i7",price:"450",image:"../img/corei7.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"Intel Core i9",price:"600",image:"../img/corei9.jfif"},{type:"ram",name:"Corsair 16gb",price:"80",image:"../img/corsair16gb.jfif"},{type:"psu",name:"Corsair PSU",price:"100",image:"../img/corsairpsu.jfif"},{type:"ram",name:"Crucial 32gb",price:"160",image:"../img/crucial32gb.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"Nvidia Geforce RTX3070",price:"750",image:"../img/gforce 3070.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"Nvidia Geforce RTX 3080",price:"950",image:"../img/gforce_3080.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"Nvidia Geforce RTX 3090",price:"1200",image:"../img/gforce_3090.jfif"},{type:"mb",name:"Gigabyte Motherboard",price:"400",image:"../img/gigabytemb.jfif"},{type:"psu",name:"Gigabyte PSU",price:"80",image:"../img/gigabytepsu.jfif"},{type:"ram",name:"Kingston 16gb",price:"90",image:"../img/kingston16gb.jfif"},{type:"mb",name:"MSI Motherboard",price:"300",image:"../img/msimb.jfif"},{type:"case",name:"Phanteks Case",price:"70",image:"../img/Phaktekscase.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"AMD Radeon 6500",price:"500",image:"../img/radeon_6500.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"AMD Radeon 6800",price:"650",image:"../img/radeon_6800.jfif"},{type:"gpu",name:"AMD Radeon 6900",price:"800",image:"../img/radeon_6900.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"AMD Ryzen 3790",price:"400",image:"../img/ryzen3790.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"AMD Ryzen 5600",price:"550",image:"../img/ryzen5600.jfif"},{type:"cpu",name:"AMD Ryzen 5800",price:"700",image:"../img/ryzen5800.jfif"},{type:"psu",name:"Seasonic PSU",price:"95",image:"../img/seasonicpsu.jfif"},{type:"case",name:"Zalmancase",price:"90",image:"../img/zalmancase.jfif"},{type:"psu",name:"Evga PSU",price:"80",image:"../img/evgapsu.jfif"}];

const search = 'Corsair 16gb';

// Find the product
const product = products.find(product => product.name === search);

// Increase the price
++product.price;

// Filter out the object from the array
const filtered = products.filter(product => product.name !== search);

// Create a new array from the filtered array,
// and the updated object.
const newProducts = [...filtered, product ];

console.log(newProducts);
```

Both these methods produce new arrays. You could also use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which operates on each array element in place (and doesn't return a new array) but because this is React I wouldn't recommend it in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the uniq name like Id and do something like

```
const changeInArr = (name, newValue) => {
const newArr = yourArray.map(elem => {
if (name === item.name) {
item.value = newValue
}
return item
}
return newer
}
```

If you need change different field, you can use a key parameter like that :

```
const changeInArr = (name, newValue, key) => {
const newArr = yourArray.map(elem => {
if (name === item.name) {
item[key] = newValue
}
return item
}
return newer
}
```

Say me if work for you

Answer (score 0):

With the current structure, the only way is to use `Array.map`. 
If you want to optimize it then you need to convert the array to the object.

```js
const products = [
  {
    type: 'cpu',
    name: 'AMD Ryzen 5800',
    price: '700',
    image: 'img/ryzen5800.jfif'
  },
  {
    type: 'cpu',
    name: 'AMD Ryzen 6000',
    price: '800',
    image: 'img/ryzen6000.jfif'
  }
]

const productObj = products.reduce((obj, product) => {
  return {
    ...obj,
    [product.name]: product
  }
}, {})

console.log(productObj)
console.log(productObj['AMD Ryzen 6000'])
```